# how can i encrypt every file with a different key using encFS

Tags: encryption, filesystems

Is there a way to encrypt every file with a separate key using encFS?

I am new to this but what I have understood till now is that the user's password is used to derive a key to encrypt the volume password. Is it true that all files inside this volume are then encrypted using this password or are there different keys for different files?